# How can i do multiple 302 redirects in htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 302-redirect

I'm currently using the following to redirect only 3-4 pages to new a site

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news1\.html$ https://www.example.com/news1.html [R,L]
RewriteRule ^news2\.html$ https://www.example.com/news2.html [R,L]
RewriteRule ^news3\.html$ https://www.example.com/news3.html [R,L]


Options -Indexes
```

However only news.1html is being redirected, not the rest of them.

How do i redirect all to their subsequent new page?

Comment: In theory, this should work just fine! I would try and remove the escape from news1.html though. It may not be necessary. It is technically correct of course. Also the ,L may not be necessary though also technically correct. Try these one at a time to see if that makes a difference. **But before doing this, clear your browser cache to make sure you are not getting the page from cache.**

Comment: Could you tell me the code? As im not too familiar with htaccess.

Redirect 302 /news.html https://www.example.com/news1.html used more than once does not seem to work either, should i be entering something at the end of each line of code?

Comment: First, I would tell you to empty your browser cache. This is likely the problem. Not sure how to do this for all browsers, but with Chrome, you would click on the icon in the upper-right hand corner that looks like three bars and go to *More tools*, then *Clear browsing data*. Your code is technically correct. Or at least I am not seeing anything wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a cache issue.

Comment: Instead of RewriteRule ^index\.html$ example.com [R,L], how do i make it so index.html and www.oldsite.com is redirected to www.example.com? Is it ^(index\.html)?$ ? old site is current webpage which index.html belongs to.

Comment: Hey brother! We all do it!! I have 30 years at this, and I still forget to clear the cache sometimes. ;-)

Comment: I am not sure I follow this comment: *Instead of RewriteRule ^index\.html$ example.com*. Do you want to do a blanket redirect from old site to new?? Or just index.html from old to new?

Comment: Secondary question already answered here... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77230/how-to-redirect-a-single-web-page-other-than-using-htaccess/77232

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this isn't with rewrite rules but with the redirect directive. Simply use

`Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm http://example.net/newfile.htm`

in your `.htaccess` file to redirect a single file from the current site to a file on another domain.